# Mutation probability

Tags: probability, statistics, biology

> Say we have a sample of DNA from  population A and population B as shown below. (Both samples taken from today).

[image]

> Find the following
>
> $$ \mathbb{P}(M>0 | T_2,...,Tn) $$
> where $T_i$ is the length of branch $i$, and $M$ is the total number of mutations happening on the branch with a solid line in the above picture. Hence, find $ \mathbb{P}(M>0) $.

I know that:

- $T_i$ are independent exponential random variables with parameter $i \choose{2}$
- $l$ is the total tree length: $l = 2T_2 + 3T_3 + \ldots nT_n$.
- The mutations occur as a Poisson process along the edges of the tree at rate $\frac{\theta}{2}$ (meaning in total it is of rate $\frac{\theta l}{2}$)

**My guess:** $$ \mathbb{P}(M>0 | T_2,...,Tn) = 1- \mathbb{P}(M=0 | T_2,...,Tn) = 1-e^{-\theta l/2} \sim exp\left(\frac{\theta l }{2}\right)$$ Is this right? If so how would we find $P(M>0)$?

Comment: You say $l$ is the length of the branch tree but you also say each branch has a length $l$, and it is quite confusing.

Comment: Is $M$ the *number* of mutations happening?  And it looks like they have to happen (in order to be counted in $M$) either on the direct line to the Neanderthal, or else up to the first branch point on the way to modern humans, is that right?  It's sort of unclear.

Comment: Yes - it is the total number of mutations happening. And you are correct - it has to happen.